# Отправка формы с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день. Отправляю форму с помощью `jQuery`, но не могу разобраться. Массив `$_FILE` приходит пустой. Подскажите, как решить проблему? Вот код отправки формы:

```
function send_form(){

            // Получаем объект для работы с формой          
               var form = $("#regi");

   // Получаем значения переменных
   var vars = {};   
   var inputs = form.find("input:text");   
   $.each(inputs, function(i, val){
    vars[$(val).attr("name")] = $(val).val();
   });
    var inputs_pass = form.find("input:password");   
   $.each(inputs_pass, function(i, val){
    vars[$(val).attr("name")] = $(val).val();
   });

    var inputs_file = form.find("input:file");   
   $.each(inputs_file, function(i, val){
    vars[$(val).attr("name")] = $(val).val();
   });

   var hidden_inputs = form.find("input:hidden");   
   $.each(hidden_inputs, function(i, val){
    vars[$(val).attr("name")] = $(val).val();
   });
   var selects = form.find("select");   
   $.each(selects, function(i, val){
    vars[$(val).attr("name")] = $(val).val();
   });
   var radios = form.find("input:radio:checked");   
   $.each(radios, function(i, val){
    vars[$(val).attr("name")] = $(val).val();
   });
   var chbxs = form.find("input:checkbox :checked");   
   $.each(chbxs, function(i, val){
    vars[$(val).attr("name")] = $(val).val();
   });

            // Скрываем блок с формой и очищаем его
            $("#formregistration").slideUp('slow', function(){
                $("#formregistration").empty();
            });

                $("#result_block").load(form.attr("action"), vars);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сегодняшний день, придется отказаться от этой затеи. Я бы соврал, если бы сказал, что это абсолютно не возможно. Есть вариант - это **XMLHttpRequest 2**, а точнее, составляющая часть этого API - технология HTML5 [File System API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), **НО** пока его поддерживает только один Chrome.

---

P.S. Вы уверены, что нужно по каждому полю пробегать, чтоб собрать все значения? Может проще это сделать одной-двумя строками?

```
var form = $("#regi");
var vars = form.serialize();
// или 
var vars = form.serializeArray();
```

Comment: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload - работает в ie7

Comment: @eicto, Так этот комментарий, вы могли бы разместить не к моему ответу, а под вопросом ТС, как вариант выхода из положения. Плагины используют для загрузки файлов апплеты (напр., flash или iframe) но не ajax в чистом виде.

Comment: ну я про то, что "нельзя" iframe по-моему нормальный выход. file api нужен чтобы с контентом файла работать в основном.